# Unable to use the captcha service by IBM WebSphere

Tags: java, captcha

i'm blocked on my work by this problem, i've a Captcha service who should work when i try to enter in a section of my web-app, but then i load this page, that's what the console shoot:

> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:412)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:258)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:376)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
>
> [28/10/16 9.31.22:272 CEST] 00000027 SystemErr     R  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:437)

Any solution?

Comment: Check if connection between Captcha service and your server works properly (e.g. try cURL GET to Captcha service from your server's terminal and see if it works).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
Was not even my Fault, the WebService who provided to give me the captcha connection was down and i dont even knew that, changing the URL of connection it works perfectly!